# Implementing an asyncExec

Tags: java, multithreading, swt

I am trying to write visual table that will display Modbus value on a live constant basis.  While I know that the everything works on its own, I cannot get this UI to multi thread.  As it currently is, this actually updates constantly, but the UI freezes if you try to minimize, close, or move the window.  This is because "go()" is a never ending loop that is interrupting the UI portion.

All I want is for the "initUI" to load, then run my "go()" method, which will update the labels in the 2nd column of my UI.

I know that most of you will not have the Modbus import that I am using, but could someone show me where and what to implement the asyncExec in initUI and in go()?  Everything I am finding on the Internet isn't tell me how to do this properly, or at least in a way where I can understand.

```
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridData;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Label;

import com.focus_sw.fieldtalk.*;

public class TableEx2 {

    int y = 21; // Number of registers
    int z = 0; // Starting registers offset
    int x = 1;
    int i;
    int j = y + z; // Number of registers plus offset
    int r = 1;
    int b = 10;
    int c = 1;
    boolean a = false;
    int ReadINT[] = new int[j];
    String IPAdd = new String("127.0.0.1");
    String Connecting = new String("Connecting...");
    String Connected = new String("Connected to " + IPAdd);

    Thread pollThread; // The cyclic poll thread
    volatile boolean pollThreadExit; // Flag to safely terminate the thread
    MbusTcpMasterProtocol mbus = new MbusTcpMasterProtocol(); // The protocol
    short readDataTable[] = new short[j]; // The data table to be read
    short writeDataTable[] = new short[j]; // The data table to be written
    String ReadData[] = new String[j];
    String RegNum[] = new String[j];

    private Label label; // Must import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Label; then
    // declare it in the class to use it.
    private Label status;
    private Display display;
    private Shell shell = new Shell(display, SWT.SHELL_TRIM | SWT.CENTER);
    private Label ModbusValues[] = new Label[j];

    public TableEx2(Display display) {
        try {
            initUI(display);
            invalidateUiData();
        }

        catch (NoClassDefFoundError e) {
            status.setText(e.toString());
        }
    }

    private void initUI(Display display) {
        shell.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, false));
        Label RegisterLabels[] = new Label[j];

        for (i = 1; i < j; i++) {
            if (i % 2 == 1) {
                GridData gd1 = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true);
                RegisterLabels[i] = new Label(shell, SWT.BORDER);
                RegisterLabels[i].setLayoutData(gd1);
                gd1.widthHint = 100;
                gd1.horizontalSpan = 1;
                RegisterLabels[i].setText(Integer.toString(b));
                b++;
            } else {
                GridData gd1 = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true);
                ModbusValues[c] = new Label(shell, SWT.BORDER);
                ModbusValues[c].setLayoutData(gd1);
                gd1.widthHint = 100;
                gd1.horizontalSpan = 1;
                ModbusValues[c].getText();
                c++;
            }
        }

        GridData gd2 = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true);
        status = new Label(shell, SWT.BORDER);
        status.setLayoutData(gd2);
        gd2.widthHint = 250;
        gd2.heightHint = 15;
        gd2.horizontalSpan = 2;
        status.getText();
        shell.setText("Modbus Tags");
        shell.pack();

        shell.open();
        start();
        go();

        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch())
                display.sleep();
        }
        display.dispose();

    }

    public void start() {

        try {
            status.setText(Connecting);
            mbus.openProtocol("127.0.0.1");
            pollThreadExit = false;
            pollThread = new Thread();
            pollThread.start();
            status.setText(Connected);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            status.setText("Unable to connect to " + IPAdd);
        }

    }

    public void stop() {
        try {
            pollThreadExit = true; // Stop thread safely
            try {
                pollThread.join();
            } catch (java.lang.InterruptedException e) { /* ignore */
            }
            mbus.closeProtocol();
            invalidateUiData();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            label.setText(e.toString());
            invalidateUiData();
        }
    }

    void invalidateUiData() {
        status.setText("Unable to see registers.");
        display.dispose();
    }

    public void go() {
        while (!pollThreadExit) {
            try {
                Thread.currentThread().sleep(50);
            } catch (java.lang.InterruptedException e) {
            }

            try {
                mbus.readMultipleRegisters(1, 10, readDataTable);
                int ModbusAdd = 1;
                int AddressMax = 10;
                for (ModbusAdd = 1; ModbusAdd <= AddressMax; ModbusAdd++) {
                    ReadINT[ModbusAdd] = (int) (readDataTable[ModbusAdd]);
                    ModbusValues[ModbusAdd].setText(Integer
                            .toString(ReadINT[ModbusAdd]));
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                status.setText("Invalid register polled");
                invalidateUiData();
            }
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Display display = new Display();
        TableEx2 ex = new TableEx2(display);
        display.dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `go` method appears to be calling `sleep` on the User Interface thread - this will block your UI completely, do not do this.

Comment: I realize that.  But I do not know any other way to properly run my go() method.  I think asyncExec is my best chance, but I do not know how to properly implement it.  If you know this or another way to multi-thread this, I would appreciate it.